# Wingpanel icons are not showing up despite installing ayatana and namarupa

Tags: wingpanel, icons

Third party app icons (Discord, Steam, etc.) are not showing up in the tray portion of the top panel on Elementary OS 6 (Odin). Native icons like network, microphone, etc. work, just not third party indicators.

I believe an alternative was to use Lafydev's [wingpanel-indicator-ayatana](https://github.com/Lafydev/wingpanel-indicator-ayatana) or [wingpanel-indicator-namarupa](https://github.com/Lafydev/wingpanel-indicator-namarupa/) but none of them are working. I added this to the indicator-application.desktop file:

```
OnlyShowIn=Unity;GNOME;Pantheon;
```

Manually started the indicator-application service, this was the output:

> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/indicator-application/indicator-application-service

> (process:4600): indicator-application-service-WARNING **: 19:54:31.377: Unable to get >watcher name 'org.kde.StatusNotifierWatcher'

> (process:4600): indicator-application-service-WARNING **: 19:54:31.377: Name Lost

Those wingpanel apps were supposed to fix this but for some reason they just aren't working.

Comment: The most relatable problem ever for people using elementary OS who just want to show a couple lousy panel indicators. Been dealing with this ever since elementary 0.4.1.

Comment: Did you install from the `.deb`s provided by those projects, or build from source? If the latter is the case, then _probably_ what you did (what _I_ did, after trying several things) was forget `--prefix=/usr` on your `meson build` command. By default it will install to `/usr/local`, and I think the `.so` file needs to be in `/usr` instead. I didn't really dig into the details, but this little tweak fixed the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

The error message you're seeing is because two `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/indicator-application/indicator-application-service`s are running, and is not alone an indication of a problem.

Try this experiment to confirm:

```
$ pkill -ef indicator-application-service
indicator-appli killed (pid 74400)

$ /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/indicator-application/indicator-application-service &
[1] 74577

$ /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/indicator-application/indicator-application-service

(process:74555): indicator-application-service-WARNING **: 17:01:41.731: Unable to get watcher name 'org.kde.StatusNotifierWatcher'

(process:74555): indicator-application-service-WARNING **: 17:01:41.731: Name Lost
```

That said, I'm now using elementary OS 7 (Horus), and both wingpanel-indicator-ayatana from Lafydev's (archived) repo *and* wingpanel-indicator-namarupa worked for me.

One thing to be careful of is not to forget `--prefix=/usr` from the `meson build` step in the install instructions of both repos (see my comment above).

It seems that `libayatana.so` installed by either project **needs to be under `/usr`**, namely in a path like `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/wingpanel`, depending on your architecture. Without the explicit flag to `meson build`, it would be installed to `/usr/local` instead. I'm not too interested in the detai/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/wingpanells, but it probably comes down to some library search path in wingpanel, or some other part of the system.

As I recall, as long as the indicator-application-service had already been started (via `~/.config/autostart` or whichever method you chose), a reboot wasn't even required. I think the build scripts restart wingpanel for you, or wingpanel restarts itself when it notices the new `.so` file—either way it was a very pleasant surprise.